# Ant command from Azure pipeline powershell task

Tags: powershell, ant, azure-pipelines

I am running ant target from azure pipeline powershell task where in it fails without any error log.

```
*[sf:deploy] Request ID for the current deploy task: 0Af2100000Tso3aCAB
[sf:deploy] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress (0/3)  -- Processing Type: 
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Failed
##[error]C:\apache-ant-1.9.14\bin\ant.bat : 
##[error]+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
##[error]    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
##[error]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
##[error] 
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.*
```

But If I run the same ant command from Powershell IDE, it gives the error.

```
*sf:deploy] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Pending
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Pending
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Pending
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Failed
C:\apache-ant-1.9.14\bin\ant.bat : 
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\apache-ant-1.9.14\bin\ant.bat -buildfile C:\Automation\salesforce_ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

BUILD FAILED
C:\Automation\salesforce_ant_43.0\sample\build.testclass.xml:78: 
*********** DEPLOYMENT FAILED ***********
Request ID: 0Af2100000TspYjCAJ
All Component Failures:*
```

Is there anything I need to check in Azure pipeline powershell task?
Please help me with this.

Thanks,
Puneet

Comment: Do you mean why Azure powershell's error message is not same detailed with the local one? In the source script of powershell, we did not get all of info then display it into the console log. In one word, the script has some filter on the error message. According to your message, the powershell is calling your local `ant.bat` to compile but facing error. This issue you could solve it locally first. Once it is succeed, it will also success in VSTS pipeline.

Comment: Hi Merlin Liang, I am running the same script locally as well as on Azure but output is coming differently in azure pipeline where in it will not display the ant command output. Locally its fine

Comment: Aah, sorry, little confused now. For the two error log you provided in question, does the first is come from Azure Devops, and the second is from local powershell? Or they are all come from where? Which agent are you using when you run the script in azure devops pipeline?

Comment: I should have been clear with the explanation.. First log is from Azure Pipeline and second one is from local Powershell... I am using hosted agent.

Comment: Got, this meet my origin understood and more clearly now. In the fifth line of your first error log, it is calling ant.bat to run the script you provided. But since the agent you used is Hosted agent, what it used is the one installed in the hosted agent. You can try with your private agent, then the ant.bat it use is your local one. Also, I recommend you'd better debug this error in your local first. If it all succeed locally, it will not facing error again in Azure Devops.

Comment: I am connecting to the same machine from Azure pipeline. It uses the same Powershell version but ant output will not be visible in Azure pipeline where in it visible locally

Comment: I reproduce with one Ant build file on my side both in powershell task and locally powershell IDE, all of them can print out the error message which point out which line does the error occurred on the file. To get clearly know whether it is a issue on our side, do you mind share a simple sample here? (Note, I am using private agent to call the local ant build file, and did not specify the debug=true. But still could see the detailed error line)

Comment: I was running the below script

"$bpath = "C:\Automation\salesforce_ant_43.0\sample\build.testclass.xml"

[xml]$myXML = Get-Content  $bpath

$xmltElt=$myXML.project.target | where {$_.Name -eq 'TestCoverage'}
$result=$xmltElt.deploy.runTest

Write-Host "$result"

if ($result -ne $null) {

Write-Host "Test classes are present"
ant -f $bpath TestCoverage

}

else {

exit 0

}
"

Comment: I am working with salesforce ant taks